# Separate string by tab characters

Tags: c#, special-characters

I have a text file that is tab-delimited.  How can I separate this string into substrings for an array by detecting the tabs?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
string s = "123\t456\t789";
string[] split = s.Split('\t');
```

Comment: thanks, CD.  I didn't realize split would take escape sequences like this.

Answer (score 6):

If you use String.split() you can split the String around any regular expression, including tabs. 
The regex that matches tabs is \t, so you could use the following example;

```
String foo = "Hello\tWorld";
String[] bar = foo.split("\t");
```

Which would return a String array containing the words *Hello* and *World*

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `String.Split` method and split on tabs (so probably first one split on newlines to get the lines and then one on tabs to get the values).

See here for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx