# Text file info to SQL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I need to write a program that takes the info from a text file and upload the into a table in SQL.

So, I've wrote a little program that takes the info from the text file and put it into TextBoxes, which seems to work:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new 
System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Chriss\Desktop\Test Eq\ATE4 Dbase 2017-05-12 - Copy.log"))
        {
            string allFile = file.ReadToEnd();
            int offset = 0;
            int length = 3;
            if (allFile.Substring(offset, length) == "NEW")
            {
                textBox1.Text = allFile.Substring(4, 10);
                textBox2.Text = allFile.Substring(15, 8);
                textBox3.Text = allFile.Substring(24, 22);
                textBox4.Text = allFile.Substring(47, 4);
                textBox5.Text = allFile.Substring(53, 7);
            }
```

The problem is that the character length changes of some "fields", so I can't go and get the info at a specific position. Another thing that might help is that the different "fields" are separated with a "Tab" space. This is what the text file looks like:

[image]

What would be the best way to get that info from the text file?

```
NEW 2017/05/12  08:27:09    05001432917TSA5009R00.  SPS2        TSA5009 R.JONES 230230  P   0
  STP   3   P   CHECKL  PACKAGING-VISUAL INSPECTION CARTON QUALITY & CONDITION  P   PRINTING FINISH & CONTENT   P   BAR CODE    P   CARTON CERTIFICATION    P   ALL PARTS ARE PRESENT   P   FOUR FEET   P   LATEST VERSION OF INSTRUCTION MANUAL    P                           1.1         G   S                               
  STP   4   P   CHECKL  COSMETIC AND CONSTRUCTION-VISUAL    ENCLOSURE AND COSMETICS P   SCRATCHES   P   PROPERLY CLEANED    P   WELDS FINISHED SMOOTH AND COLOUR REMOVED    P   SINK MARKS  P   FIT AND FINISH  P   COMPONENTS AND MATERIALS    P   COMPONENTS/ MATERIALS AS PER PRODUCT DESCRIPTION    P                   3.4         S   S                               
  STP   5   P   CHECKL  COSMETICS AND CONSTRUCTION-VISUAL   COMPONENTS AND MATERIALS AS PER AGENCY REPORT   P   FLASH AND SHARP EDGES   P   RATING LABEL    P   CERTIFICTAION MARKING AND REQUIRED DATA P   LABEL OR IMPRINT PERMANENT  P   REQUIRED WARNING LABELS PRESENT AND LEDGIBLE    P   PRODUCT ARTWORK P                           3.5         G   S                               
  STP   6   P   CHECKL  PERFORMANCE TEST AS PER UL197   PERFORMANCE TEST 100% OF PRODUCTION P   THERMOSTAT FUNCTION P   CORD STAIN RELIEF   P   INDICATOR FUNCTION  P   POWER CABLE S.A 230V    P   PILOT LIGHT RED 230V    P                                   3.7         G   S                               
  STP   9   P   DSHORT1P        0.00    P   0.000                                                                       10.2    3   0.5 0.4 0                               
  STP   10  P   ECON        0.12    P   1.20        12.21                                                               15.0    3   1.5 0.3                                 
  STP   11  P   INSMEG      508 P   5.0 P   0.0                                                             20.3    2   2.5 0   500                             
  STP   12  P   INSLEAK     1500    P   0.00    P                                                                   24.4    1   2.5 5   0   1000                            
  STP   14  P   LOADELA ELEMENT 7.698   P   999.0       230.000     7.698       1770        1770        0.00000                             37.9    5   2   8.6 1.5 .5  0   0   A   1           
  PRN   PIC DSCF1383.JPG    50  50
  PRN   TX1 Serial No.: 05001432917TSA5009R00.      12  0   0   0   B
  PRN   TX1 2017/05/12 08:27 SPS2,      11  0   0   0   B
  PRN   TX1 Schedule: TSA5009       10  0   0   0   B
  PRN   TX1 Operator: R.JONES       10  0   0   0   B
  PRN   GAP 0   0   0   0
  PRN   TX1 TSA5009     10  0   0   0   B
  PRN   TX1 TSA5009 230V-50HZ       10  0   0   0   B
  PRN   TX1 MORE MODEL INFO     10  0   0   0   B
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, CARTON QUALITY & CONDITION   Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, PRINTING FINISH & CONTENT    Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, BAR CODE Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, CARTON CERTIFICATION Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, ALL PARTS ARE PRESENT    Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, FOUR FEET    Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, LATEST VERSION OF INSTRUCTION MANUAL Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, ENCLOSURE AND COSMETICS  Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, SCRATCHES    Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, PROPERLY CLEANED Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, WELDS FINISHED SMOOTH AND COLOUR REMOVED Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, SINK MARKS   Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, FIT AND FINISH   Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, COMPONENTS AND MATERIALS Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, COMPONENTS/ MATERIALS AS PER PRODUCT DESCRIPTION Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, COMPONENTS AND MATERIALS AS PER AGENCY REPORT    Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, FLASH AND SHARP EDGES    Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, RATING LABEL Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, CERTIFICTAION MARKING AND REQUIRED DATA  Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, LABEL OR IMPRINT PERMANENT   Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, REQUIRED WARNING LABELS PRESENT AND LEDGIBLE Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, PRODUCT ARTWORK  Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, PERFORMANCE TEST 100% OF PRODUCTION  Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, THERMOSTAT FUNCTION  Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, CORD STAIN RELIEF    Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, INDICATOR FUNCTION   Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, POWER CABLE S.A 230V Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, PILOT LIGHT RED 230V Pass    10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Dead Short Test 0.00 A  10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Ground Bonding Test 0.12 Ohms   10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Insulation Test 508V    508 V   5.0 MOhms   10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Insulation Test 1500V   1 500 V   0.00 mA   10  0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Load Test 0V, ELEMENT   7.698 A 10  0   0   0   G   0
  PRN   GAP 0   0   0   0
  PRN   TX1 PASS        10  0   0   0   G
END
NEW 2017/05/12  12:11:01    05001475617FHG7552R01.  ATE 3 PHASE VOLLRATH    FHG7552 R.JONES 400230  P   0
  STP   2   P   CHECKL  CHECK ITEM  BASE MOUNTING BRACKET WELDED CORRECTLY  P   PAINTWORK ON BASE CORRECT   P   ALL MOUNTING BOLTS ARE FASTENED P   MOTOR HAS ADEQUATE OIL  P   BEARING SLEEVES AND DRIVE SHAFT PRESSED CORRECTLY   P   ALL COMPONENTS ARE GREASED PROPERLY P   BEARING HOUSING PROPERLY MOUNTED ON BASE    P                           0.3         G   S                               
  STP   3   P   CHECKL  CHECK ITEM  TOP & BOTTOM SPROCKETS MOUNTED CORRECTLY    P   SPROCKETS ARE SQUARE- IN LINE WITH EACH OTHER   P   CHAIN IS GREASED-MOUNTED CORRECTLY  P   CHAIN DOES NOT HAVE A LOT OF SLACK  P   BODY WRAP IS FREE FROM DENTS-SCRATCHES-BURNS    P   WIRING  IS CORRECT AND NEATLY CABLE TIED    P   CHECK START-STOP & SELECTOR SWITCH OPERATIONAL  P   FITMENT OF WORM-KNIFE-PLATE &LOCK RING IS CORRECT   P                   1.3         G   S                               
  STP   4   P   CHECKL  CHECK ITEM  BARREL CENTERED AND FASTENED PROPERLY   P   FRONT STUD FLUSH ON FACE OF WORM    P   WORM SLOTS INTO DRIVE SHAFT EASILY  P   WORM ROTATES FREELY IN BARREL   P   FITMMENT OF PLATE MUST BE HALF INTO BARREL  P   FITMENT OF TRAY IS CORRECT  P   HANDGUARD SHIELD MOUNTED CORECTLY   P   BRANDING AND SERIAL PLATE DATA IS CORRECT   P                   1.5         G   S                               
  STP   5   P   CHECKL  CHECK ITEM  WARNING LABELS PRESENT  P   SERIAL NUMBER ENGRAVED ON BARREL,WORM,LOCKRING  P   SERIAL NUMBER ENGRAVED ON BEARING HOUSING & SPROCKET;MOTOR  P   RED INDICATOR ARROW ON BARRELL  P   UNIT PROPERLY SHRINKED & CRATED P   UNIT IS PROPERLY BOLTED TO PALLET   P                                   1.7         G   S                               
  STP   6   P   CHECKL  ACCESSORY LIST  1X19 SPANNER    P   1X STOMPER  P   1X NUT SPANNER  P   2 X KNIVES  P   1 X 4.76MM PLATE    P   1 X 12.7MM PLATE    P   INSTRUCTION MANUAL  P   SPLASH GUARD    P                   2.0         G   S                               
  STP   7   P   CHECKL  ACCESSORY LIST  1  X 5MM ALLEN KEY  P   4 PLASTIC FEET  P   ALL   ACCESSORIES PACKED IN BOX P   ACCESSORIES WRAPPED P   ACCESSORY BOX SHRINKED TO MACHINE   P                                           2.2         G   S                               
  STP   10  P   DSHORT3P        0.05    P   0.64    P   0.12    P   226.694                                                     12.3    3   1.5 10  0                               
  STP   11  P   ECON        0.00    P   12.21       5.07                                                                15.8    2   1.5 100                                 
  STP   12  P   INSMEG      497 P   10.0    P   0.2                                                             21.3    3   2.5 1   400                             
  STP   13  P   INSLEAK     1153    P   1.09    P                                                                   26.8    3   2.5 4   0   1100                            
  STP   16  P   LOADEL3W        5598    P   0.2 P   391.635     4.575       4.543       5.176       1792        1779        2027                36.8    5   2   5500    100 1200    0.5 1   A               
  PRN   TX1 Serial No.: 05001475617FHG7552R01.      8   0   0   0   B
  PRN   TX1 2017/05/12 12:11 ATE 3 PHASE, VOLLRATH      7   0   0   0   B
  PRN   TX1 Schedule: FHG7552       10  0   0   0   B
  PRN   TX1 Operator: R.JONES       10  0   0   0   B
  PRN   GAP
  PRN   TX1 THREE PHASE 400V-50HZ       7   0   0   0   B
  PRN   TX1 MORE MODEL INFO     7   0   0   0   B
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, BASE MOUNTING BRACKET WELDED CORRECTLY   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, PAINTWORK ON BASE CORRECT    Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, ALL MOUNTING BOLTS ARE FASTENED  Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, MOTOR HAS ADEQUATE OIL   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, BEARING SLEEVES AND DRIVE SHAFT PRESSED CORRECTLY    Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, ALL COMPONENTS ARE GREASED PROPERLY  Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, BEARING HOUSING PROPERLY MOUNTED ON BASE Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, TOP & BOTTOM SPROCKETS MOUNTED CORRECTLY Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, SPROCKETS ARE SQUARE- IN LINE WITH EACH OTHER    Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, CHAIN IS GREASED-MOUNTED CORRECTLY   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, CHAIN DOES NOT HAVE A LOT OF SLACK   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, BODY WRAP IS FREE FROM DENTS-SCRATCHES-BURNS Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, WIRING  IS CORRECT AND NEATLY CABLE TIED Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, CHECK START-STOP & SELECTOR SWITCH OPERATIONAL   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, FITMENT OF WORM-KNIFE-PLATE &LOCK RING IS CORRECT    Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, BARREL CENTERED AND FASTENED PROPERLY    Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, FRONT STUD FLUSH ON FACE OF WORM Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, WORM SLOTS INTO DRIVE SHAFT EASILY   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, WORM ROTATES FREELY IN BARREL    Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, FITMMENT OF PLATE MUST BE HALF INTO BARREL   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, FITMENT OF TRAY IS CORRECT   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, HANDGUARD SHIELD MOUNTED CORECTLY    Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, BRANDING AND SERIAL PLATE DATA IS CORRECT    Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, WARNING LABELS PRESENT   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, SERIAL NUMBER ENGRAVED ON BARREL,WORM,LOCKRING   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, SERIAL NUMBER ENGRAVED ON BEARING HOUSING & SPROCKET;MOTOR   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, RED INDICATOR ARROW ON BARRELL   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, UNIT PROPERLY SHRINKED & CRATED  Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, UNIT IS PROPERLY BOLTED TO PALLET    Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, 1X19 SPANNER Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, 1X STOMPER   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, 1X NUT SPANNER   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, 2 X KNIVES   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, 1 X 4.76MM PLATE Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, 1 X 12.7MM PLATE Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, INSTRUCTION MANUAL   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, SPLASH GUARD Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, 1  X 5MM ALLEN KEY   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, 4 PLASTIC FEET   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, ALL   ACCESSORIES PACKED IN BOX  Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, ACCESSORIES WRAPPED  Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Checklist, ACCESSORY BOX SHRINKED TO MACHINE    Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Dead Short Test Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Earth Con. Test Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Insulation 500V DC  Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Insulation 1250V/1500V  Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Load Test   Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
   PRN  TX2 Earth Leak Test Pass    7   0   0   0   G   0
  PRN   GAP
  PRN   TX1 PASS        10  0   0   0   G
END
```

Comment: If the file is separated by tabs, you can't use `Substring` like this. Have you tried `string.Split('\t')`?

Comment: @chirss is there a chance of any space or tab within a column (feild)

Comment: From the fields that I need to get from this text file, no, no spaces in a field.

Comment: This is old 120 characters per line used to go to the ancient high speed line printers. Use wordpad (not notepad) to view data.  I suspect notepad isn't properly showing the RTF characters. Have parsed lots of these files for over 40 years. I think you need to use fix column width reads based on the data in the 3rd column.  I also think the file contains multiple records with each record starting with NEW in column 1.  All other rows the text starts in column 3.   I would like to see sample of the text and not a screen capture with multiple records.

Comment: @jdweng, does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no chance of tab within a field or column you can use string.Split()

Refer 
[Separate string by tab characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797647/separate-string-by-tab-characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use character separators to at beginning and end of each word. This way you even if the field lengths varies you have to search just for the field separator (char(28) Ascii value). For different lines you can set segment separators (char(30)). If further separation is required is required group separator(char(29)) can be used.

Eg:
chat(30)+char(28)+STP+char(28)+3char(28)+P+char(28)+CHECKL+char(28)+PACKAGING-VISUAL INSPECTION.....next line
chat(30)+char(28)+STP+char(28)+3char(28)+.....
so on

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Process(FILENAME);

        }
    }
    public enum FUNCTION_TYPES
    {
        STEP,
        PRINT
    }
    public enum PRINT_TYPES
    {
        PIC,
        GAP,
        TXT1,
        TXT2
    }
    public class Process
    {
        public static List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public List<Function> functions = null;

        public Process() 
        {
            functions = new List<Function>();
        }
        public Process(string filename)
        {
            Process newProcess = null;

            string cmdPattern = @"^(?'cmd'[^\s]+)";
            string newPattern = @"^(?'cmd'[^\s]+)\s+(?'date'[^\s]+)\s+(?'time'[^\s]+)\s+(?'description'.*)";
            Match match;


            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string inputLine = "";
            while((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                string command = Regex.Match(inputLine, cmdPattern).Groups["cmd"].Value;

                switch (command)
                {
                    case "NEW" :
                        newProcess = new Process();
                        processes.Add(newProcess);
                        match = Regex.Match(inputLine, newPattern);
                        date = DateTime.Parse(match.Groups["date"].Value + " " + match.Groups["time"].Value);
                        description = match.Groups["description"].Value;
                        break;
                    case "STP":
                        newProcess.functions.Add(new Step(inputLine));
                        break;
                    case "PRN":
                        newProcess.functions.Add(new Print(inputLine));
                        break;
                    case "END":
                        newProcess = null;
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    public class Function
    {
        public FUNCTION_TYPES function { get; set; }
    }
    public class Step : Function
    {
        public int number { get; set; }
        public List<string> stepArray { get; set; }

        public Step(string stepStr)
        {
            function = FUNCTION_TYPES.STEP;
            stepArray = stepStr.Split(new string[] {" P "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
            string stepPattern = @"^(?'cmd'[^\s]+)\s+(?'number'[^\s]+)";
            Match match = Regex.Match(stepArray[0], stepPattern);
            number = int.Parse(match.Groups["number"].Value);
        }
    }
    public class Print : Function
    {
        public PRINT_TYPES printType { get; set; }
        public string imageFilename { get; set; }
        public int imageHeight { get; set; }
        public int imageWidth { get; set; }

        public string functionName { get; set; }
        public string[] functionArray { get; set; }

        public int[] gapArray { get; set; }

        public string txName { get; set; }
        public string[] txArray { get; set; }

        public Print(string printStr)
        {
            Match match;

            function = FUNCTION_TYPES.PRINT;

            string typePattern = @"^(?'cmd'[^\s]+)\s+(?'type'[^\s]+)";

            match = Regex.Match(printStr, typePattern);
            string typeStr = match.Groups["type"].Value;


            switch (typeStr)
            {
                case "PIC" :
                    printType = PRINT_TYPES.PIC;
                    string picturePattern = @"^(?'cmd'[^\s]+)\s+(?'type'[^\s]+)\s+(?'filename'[^\s]+)\s+(?'height'[^\s]+)\s+(?'width'.*)";
                    match = Regex.Match(printStr, picturePattern);

                    imageFilename = match.Groups["filename"].Value;
                    imageHeight = int.Parse(match.Groups["height"].Value);
                    imageWidth = int.Parse(match.Groups["width"].Value);
                    break;
                case "TX1":
                    printType = PRINT_TYPES.TXT1;

                    string tx1Pattern = @"^(?'cmd'[^\s]+)\s+(?'type'[^\s]+)\s+(?'txname'.+)(?'tx1'\d+)\s+(?'tx2'\d+)\s+(?'tx3'\d+)\s+(?'tx4'\d+)\s+(?'tx5'\w+)$";
                    match = Regex.Match(printStr, tx1Pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
                    txName = match.Groups["txname"].Value;
                    txArray = new string[] {
                        match.Groups["tx1"].Value,
                        match.Groups["tx2"].Value,
                        match.Groups["tx3"].Value,
                        match.Groups["tx4"].Value,
                        match.Groups["tx5"].Value
                    };

                    break;
                case "TX2":
                    printType = PRINT_TYPES.TXT2;

                    string tx2Pattern = @"^(?'cmd'[^\s]+)\s+(?'type'[^\s]+)\s+(?'txname'.+)\s+Pass\s+(?'tx1'\d+)\s+(?'tx2'\d+)\s+(?'tx3'\d+)\s+(?'tx4'\d+)\s+(?'tx5'\w+)\s+(?'tx6'\d+)$";
                    match = Regex.Match(printStr, tx2Pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
                    txName = match.Groups["txname"].Value;
                    txArray = new string[] {
                        match.Groups["tx1"].Value,
                        match.Groups["tx2"].Value,
                        match.Groups["tx3"].Value,
                        match.Groups["tx4"].Value,
                        match.Groups["tx5"].Value,
                        match.Groups["tx6"].Value
                    };

                    break;
                case "GAP":
                    printType = PRINT_TYPES.GAP ;

                    string[] gapArrayStr = printStr.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    gapArray = gapArrayStr.Skip(2).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```