# How to find text between two tabs

Tags: c#, parsing, text

I have a file that looks similar like the following:

Tomas | Nordstrom | Sweden | Europe | World

(the character "|" in the above line represents a tab, new column)

Now I want a string containing only the text in the 4th column.

I have succeeded to find characters in a certain spot in the line. But that spot changes according to the number och characters in each column.
I could really need some nice input on this.

Thanks in advance.

/Tomas

Comment: Look up `String.Split`.

Comment: Split by `\t` and go to index 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separate string by tab characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797647/separate-string-by-tab-characters)

Comment: If they are guaranteed to be single words you could do a regex with "\w+"

Comment: Read [String split method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of string split question. The answer does not require splitting a string

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the `Split` method like this:

```
string s = "Tomas|Nordstrom|Sweden|Europe|World";
string[] stringArray = s.Split( new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.None );

Console.WriteLine( stringArray[3] );
```

This will print out "Europe", because that is located at index 3 in stringArray.

Edit:

The same can be achieved using Regex like this:

```
string[] stringRegex = Regex.Split( s, @"\|+" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic algorithm would be iterating characters, until n-1 tabs found, then take chars up to the next tab or the end of string.

Depending on requirements, if performance is critical, you might need to implement a scanning algorithm manually.

You might be surprising how slow is string splitting. Well - it's not not by itself, but the overall approach requires:

- Scanning to the end of the string
- Creation of all of the split parts on heap
- Collecting garbage

Consider following benchmark of the two approaches:

```
void Main()
{
    string source = "Tomas\tNordstrom\tSweden\tEurope\tWorld";

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    string result = null;

    var n = 100000000;

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result = FindBySplitting(source);
    }

    sw.Stop();

    var splittingNsop = (double)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / n * 1000000.0;
    Console.WriteLine("Splitting. {0} ns/op",splittingNsop);

    Console.WriteLine(result);

    sw.Restart();

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result = FindByScanning(source);
    }

    sw.Stop();

    var scanningNsop = (double)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / n * 1000000.0;
    Console.WriteLine("Scanning. {0} ns/op",
        scanningNsop);

    Console.WriteLine(result);

    Console.WriteLine("Scanning over splitting: {0}", splittingNsop / scanningNsop);
}

string FindBySplitting(string s)
{
    return s.Split('\t')[3];
}

string FindByScanning(string s)
{
    int l = s.Length, p = 0, q = 0, c = 0;
    while (c++ < 4 - 1)
        while (p < l && s[p++] != '\t')
            ;
    for (q = p; q < l && s[q] != '\t'; q++)
        ;
    return s.Substring(p, q - p);
}
```

Scanning algorithm implemented in pure C# outperforms the splitting one implemented on the low level by a factor of 4.6 on my laptop:

```
Splitting. 174.81 ns/op
Europe
Scanning. 37.58 ns/op
Europe
Scanning over splitting: 4.65167642362959
```

Comment: While this is a good answer, I can't stand the use of single letter variable names, unless they are used only within the very narrow scope of a for loop or lambda expression or things like that. Please consider editing your code to give your variables meaningful names. And it's not only the single letters. What is `count` used for? You have to read and understand the code to know. If you would have called it `delimiterCount` you wouldn't have to read the entire code to understand it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Don't agree about variable names. Edited the code though to make it more consistent. I recommend you to check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You don't have to agree with me; this is just my opinion. However, it is based on experience (mine and others) - The more readable the code the easier it is to maintain it. Just for kicks, come back to this post a year from now and check how much time and effort it takes to understand what you wrote here. I guarantee that it would be easier if you used meaningful names. BTW, unless doing this type of thing in a tight loop, the performance difference between split and your code is completely negligible - and hardly worth the effort of writing the `FindByScanning` method in the first place.